# mongo db schema relational or in collection

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a side project at the moment that will hopefully help understand Mongo. I am coming from a MySQL world so some of the concepts are a bit strange to me at minutes.

My side project is essentially a project organiser, a project can have 3 areas where a a user can upload multiple files/images, project assests, work in progress, and deliverables.

So should I be creating collections for assets, wip and deliverables and then link them to the project? Using some like,

```
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "projects"
```

Or should they be part of the projects schema giving each file a type instead making the project schema look something like,

```
    // Create schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  brief: {
    type: String,
    default: "No brief given"
  },
  date_due: {
    type: Date
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  files: [
       name: {
           type: String
       },
       filepath: {
           type: String
       },
       type: {
          type: String
       }
  ]
});
```

Potentially there will be 1000s of rows in the collection if I were to ever launch the tool

Is there an accepted way of doing what would ordinarily be an 1:n relationship in a relational database?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way but you could use subdocuments for assets, wip etc on Project model and then ref for project on Profile model. You could query projects without Profile model but I don't think you will query assets or wip without Project model.